# При выполнении remove() отбрасывает на верх страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Пытаюсь сделать удаление объекта и всё ок, но при клике  меня отбрасывает на верх страницы. Это не очень удобно с точки зрения интерфейса .  Как этого избежать?

```
$( '#upload .change_image').on('click' , function(e){

                            var del_div = this.parentNode;
                            del_div.remove();});


<div id="upload" class="clearfix">
                                                    <div>
                            <div class="step3 step">
                        <span class="step-name">step 3</span>
                        <div class="top-text clear width-90">
                             <p>Download picture :</p>                               
                        </div>
                            <div id="picture_step" style="display: none;">
                                <div class="column-3"><label>Download picture:</label></div>
                                <div class="column-3 ">
                                    <div class="fileUpload" id="uploader">
                                        <span>Push to download a file</span>
                                        <input class="input-smaller" accept="image/*" type="file" required="" id="file-select" name="photos[]" aria-required="true">            
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="error-idea-page"> 
                                        <label id="file-select-error" class="error" for="file-select">Choose a picture, please.</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="characters ">
                                    <a id="photo" class="popup-with-form work-how video" href="#how-to-take-photo" style="margin-left: 0; float: right; "><span class="how howtowords">How  to take a photo correctly?</span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="step-preloader">
                                <img class="" src="http://www.site.com/wp-content/themes/theme/images/preloader.gif" alt="" title="">                               </div>
                        <div id="upload" class="clearfix">
                                                    <div>
                            <div class="crop"><img src="http://www.site.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2-1-630x423-1.jpg" alt="http://www.site.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2-1-630x423-1.jpg"></div>
                        <a href="#" class="change_image" title="Удалить файл" data-path="/home/fasadtec/site.com/www/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/2-1-630x423-1.jpg">&nbsp;</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите хоть какой-то пример (скрин, гифку) "отбрасывания", а еще лучше - разметку, с которой этот код работает.

Comment: Добавил по максимуму

Comment: Переход на верх страницы происходит из-за  `href="#"` в теге **<a>**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$( '#upload .change_image').on('click' , function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // отменяем переход по ссылке
    var del_div = this.parentNode;
    del_div.remove();
});
```